# Finding length of a side to make two other sides perpendicular

Tags: geometry

[image: Diagram!]

I am trying to solve this problem but the steps are not so obvious to me. So to my understanding, if $CD\perp AB$ means that $\triangle ADC$ and $\triangle BDC$ will be right triangles but I do not know how to progress from that.

Comment: Hint:  the three right triangles are all similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $h=\overline {CD}$.

We note that the two small right triangles are similar.  In particular, $\angle CAD=\angle DCB$.  We deduce that $$\frac h4=\frac 6h\implies h^2=24$$

Let $b=\overline {AC}$.  We have $$b^2=4^2+h^2=16+24=40\implies b=2\sqrt {10}$$

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is number 2 which is:($2\sqrt {10}$).
[image]

Comment: This is an interesting method!

Answer (score 1):

There is a theorem. Where given $\triangle ABC$ with $\angle C=90^{\circ}$ (refer to diagram below!), we have the following: $$CD=\sqrt{AD\cdot DB}\\AC=\sqrt{AD\cdot AB}\\BC=\sqrt{BD\cdot AB}$$
To have the angles cut by the altitude right angles. (meaning $\angle ADC=\angle CDB=90^{\circ}$)

[image: Triangle ABC with C=90]

**Note:** This can be proven by using similar triangles.

So with your example, we have $$AC=\sqrt{4\cdot 10}=2\sqrt{10}$$

Meaning the correct answer choice is

- $2\sqrt{6}$
- $\boxed{2\sqrt{10}}$
- $2\sqrt{15}$
- $4\sqrt{2}$